# При деплое из docker-registry в kubernetes выходит ошибка

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Мой сервер Centos 7 
kubernetes 
docker-registry

При попытки задеплоить из docker-registry в kubernetes у меня выходит ошибка.

**Failed to pull image "myhost:5000/busybox"**:

rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon:

Get https://myhost:5000/v2/: x509: cannot validate certificate for myhost because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

**Warning  Failed      (x2 over )  kubelet, pr40      Error: ErrImagePull**

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем убив кучу времени. Я решил плюнуть на смоподпесные сертификаты и воспользовался LetsEncrypt взлетел с первого раза. 
Если что вот сылка на мой же вопрос по этой теме. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603625/docker-pull-image-without-ssl-in-kubernetes-with-docker-private-registry/58610460?noredirect=1#comment103563775_58610460